# Add src attribute to iframe using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#container").click(function(){
      $("#myiframe").attr('src', 'example.com');
   });
});
```

This doesn't work? The container is actually is a lightbox. The reason I am not defining the src attribute by default is because iframe loads even when lightbox isn't shown yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

`$("#myiframe").get(0).contentWindow.location.href = 'example.com';`

I think setting src isn't going to do anything after page load.

Comment: Ok it does work.. I don't know why it didn't work on the first day I tested it... But how do I unload it?

Comment: simply do `$("#myiframe").get(0).contentWindow.location.href = 'about:blank';`